# How do I solve "Middleware "strapi::session": App keys are required" error in my deployment of Strapi to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, strapi

I'm following [the official instructions](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/heroku.html) to deploy my [strapi starter app](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-starter-next-corporate) to Heroku. The app runs fine locally. The only thing I left out in my deployment instructions were installing the PG node module (it is already installed because my local app uses Postgresql).

Accessing the Heroku logs, I see this:

```
error: Middleware "strapi::session": App keys are required. 
Please set app.keys in config/server.js (ex: keys: ['myKeyA', 'myKeyB'])
```

Maybe this is an important detail: I followed this process once, and everything worked. I was able to deploy to Heroku. I tried it again and it didn't work. I was thinking maybe Heroku had a problem with me re-using an app name, but I tried to name the app something different in Heroku and I still had the same error.

Is heroku looking in the wrong place for my server.js file? Should it be looking in my "./config/env/production" folder instead of my "./config" folder?

Per the instructions, here is my ./config/env/production/database.js

```
const parse = require('pg-connection-string').parse;
const config = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: 'postgres',
    connection: {
      host: config.host,
      port: config.port,
      database: config.database,
      user: config.user,
      password: config.password,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      },
    },
    debug: false,
  },
});
```

Here is my ./config/env/production/server.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    url: env('MY_HEROKU_URL'),
});
```

And here is my ./config/server.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
});
```

my package.json for good measure:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-graphql": "^4.0.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.0.6",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.0.6",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.0.6",
    "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
    "pg": "8.6.0",
    "pg-connection-string": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "name": "backend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "f64b509e-2d95-4464-8d39-d6f0d1c7a31a",
    "template": "@strapi/template-corporate@^1.0.0",
    "starter": "@strapi/starter-next-corporate"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.x.x <=16.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I'm running Node v14.18.3 and NPM v6.14.15

Comment: Heroku will run the app for me now, but only if I list the keys directly in the ./config/env/production/server.js file. Anyone know why Heroku isn't picking up my global variables set in my root .env file?

Comment: Turns out my .env was in .gitignore so heroku couldn't read the keys.

Comment: I was able to add the keys to heroku directly with the "heroku config:set" command so I could keep my .env in .gitignore

Answer (score 15):

I solved it with this in `./config/env/production/server.js`

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  url: env("MY_HEROKU_URL"),
  proxy: true,
  app: {
    keys: env.array("APP_KEYS", ["testKey1", "testKey2"]),
  },
});
```

testKey1, testKey2 are just placeholders and need to be replaced by 2 random keys via CONFIG VAR in heroku

```
APP_KEYS=someSecret,anotherSecret
```

`proxy: true` was also important. Else it throws a `Cannot send secure cookie over unencrypted connection`

Comment: Thanks. I found that my .env file was in .gitignore, so when I included it, Heroku was able to access the app keys in the .env file. Then I didn't need to include them in the server.js

Comment: please avoid committing your env file or hardcoding them. instead, you can set the env from heroku cli or dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, this should be in the doc.

Comment: Am i the only one for who this answer makes no sense? Replace placeholder by 2 random keys? 

I was able to get this to work by replacing with keys from heroku dashboard by revealing env variables - strapi keys.

    keys: env.array("APP_KEYS", ["DATABASE_URL", "MY_HEROKU_URL", "NODE_ENV"]),

Comment: Are there suggestions for secure keys? (minimum recommended length, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

Adding the environment variables to your file as @Temo mentioned is not the right solution. Although it works it poses quite some security threats.

What you should do is add the `APP_KEYS` to your environment variables on Heroku.
You can generate a new key by creating a file with this code:

```
// filename: generateCode.js
const crypto = require('crypto')
console.log(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'))
```

and then running it from the console with:

```
node generateCode.js
```

The code it generates looks something like `foP7OJcuRhCw1sTR6EfZPw==`. Use that as your APP_KEY in Heroku.

Answer (score 7):

just create `.env` file in root of your project like this:

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=1337
APP_KEYS=jP8pb1lYsAhnmURarewxhA==,34xnLMYHY5jiU7ONTstTqQ==
```

Answer (score 4):

On Heroku, for that particular app, navigate to **Settings->Config vars** and add your environment variables there.

Answer (score 2):

So you just need to create a variable in Heroku settings->config vars called `APP_KEYS`. And value of this variable you can get from your `.env` file where you should have `APP_KEYS` variable with value.

Answer (score -10):

Just remove .env from git ignore.
Then push again.

Comment: The whole point of using an `.env` file is so you aren't committing your configuration data. Committing it isn't a good idea, and `.env` files aren't a good fit on Heroku. A the other answers have said, use Config Vars instead. Both `.env` files and Config Vars are just convenient ways to set environment variables.

Comment: Please don't push your .env file into your repository

Comment: sure fire way to lose your job